# Django form returns 404 Page not found if input type file included

Tags: python, django, cpanel

I am using Django==2.1 and Pillow==7.1.2

When I include `<input type="file">` in django form and post it, 404 page not found is the error i get.

My template consists of this form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if success %}
        <p>Success</p>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.models import Upload
def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        myfile = request.FILES.get('file')
        upload = Upload(myfile=myfile)
        upload.save()
        data = {
            'success': "Success"
        }
        return render(request, 'file.html', data)
    else:
        return render(request, 'file.html')
```

urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.upload, name="upload"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/my/path/to/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The code works fine on localhost but I get error when I host it on CPanel shared hosting. If I remove the `<input type="file">` and try `<input type="text">` it works properly. Also my media files are being served properly only the upload is causing issue

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this same error a couple of times when am deploying a django app on a shared host.

In production, django does not serve static and media files directly like it does in development.
**option one**
if you want django to serve the media files directly, please use `pip install mod_wsgi` on the production server[Follow the instructions here](https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/)

**option two**
use a media bucket storage forexample AWS, but you can use the free one provided by github by creating a public github repo, then generate access token for it.Afterwords install  django-github-s3.
then in your settings.py add this code

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "github_storages.backend.BackendStorages"
GITHUB_HANDLE = "your_github_username"
ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token_generated"
GITHUB_REPO_NAME = "repo_name"
MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME = "media_folder"

**NB:** don't forget to add `'github_storages'` to your installed_apps
```